# Is it OK to access instance variables directly in an instance method of the same class to read their value?

Tags: objective-c

I have an instance variable -> mXYZ
I have read at many places that its better to have accessors for these methods.
But if I am only using them inside the class and that too for reading.

I know that to modify a instance var, we should always use a setter as there is some work to be done like releasing old object being pointed to and few other things.

But getters just simply return what the instance variable is, Then is it necessary that I use a getter to access it within the class ?

the variable is not be accessed outside the class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a private instance variable in your class then whether to just access it directly or define a property depends on:

- how you use it: do you need to manage (de)allocation, do you wish to delay delay creation, it is a pseudo-variable (e.g. storing temp in F but having both F and C properties)
- the type of memory management you use: manual (retain/release) or automatic (ARC or garbage collection)

Properties are usually of little benefit for primitive-typed variables, pseudo-variables being  an obvious counter-example.

Under automatic memory management one of the most common uses of properties - to localise and handle retain/release - is removed. But if you need copy-on-assignment semantics properties are better than direct access.

Under manual memory management then properties have a distinct advantage - the memory management is localised, and with `@synthesize` provided by the language. However, as you remark, for reading a variable direct access is often fine.

Overall *you* know your class and which style of memory management you're using, so can pick the best solution for your private instance variables. There is no general "right" answer.

Answer (score 6):

Although you are probably right that getters **usually** just return the value, the same logic applies to them as to the setters. That is to say, it is possible that the getter is doing some important extra work that you would bypass if you tried to access the variable directly.

For example, a class might defer loading the values of some of its properties (i.e. ivar values) from disk or a remote server until one of them is accessed via its getter.